# Convert bash string into JSON object using python

Tags: python, json, bash, sockets

I have a key value pair that I want to export from the bash script which the following python is embedded in.
Excerpt from bash script:

```
output_test="ip:192.168.1.150,status:up"
export output_test
```

Embedded python within above bash script

```
python -c "$(cat << 'EOF'
import socket
import os
import json
bash_output=string(os.environ["output_test"])
sd = dict(u.split(":") for u in output_test.split(","))
print json.dumps(sd)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 15000))
s.send(bytes(json.dumps(s)))
result = json.loads(s.recv(1024))
print result
s.close()
EOF
)"
```

I'm quite new to Python I will admit I've hashed this together after intense speed research, and it's all I am going to need it to do in my scripts. Send name value pairs to a socket as a json array. Also, will the name I give the JSON object in the python, sd in the example above, become the name of the JSON array? - I will want to give it a meaningful name in the final version.

The error I'm getting is string not defined, which I think it means the string bash_output

Comment: There is no module called `dictionary` in standard python. You never assign a value to `output_test`, presumably you are missing `output_test = os.environ['output_test']`. No the name you assign the json will have no affect on the json ouput.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @achampion, output_test seems to be mixed up with bash_output. A quick fix would probably be:

```
bash_output=os.environ["output_test"]
sd = dict(u.split(":") for u in bash_output.split(","))
```

You may also consider just not using environment variable this way:

```
$ output_test="ip:192.168.1.150,status:up"
$ python -c "$(cat << 'EOF'
import socket
import os
import json
import sys
bash_output = sys.argv[1]
sd = dict(u.split(":") for u in bash_output.split(","))
print json.dumps(sd)
EOF
)" $output_test
{"status": "up", "ip": "192.168.1.150"}
```

Comment: Unfortunately there's no builtin `string` in Python, so that quick fix is wrong.

Comment: Yep, sorry, forgot to remove the string(...) which is wrong too

Comment: Can anyone tell me why the following string is converting the commas to spaces and how I can correct it? Bash is doing this
`output="Name:plugin,Timestamp:${timestamp},UUID:b4238ca2-cb8d-11e4-8731-1681e6b88ec1,RecDays:${NC_recDays}`
I'm trying to use in a different plugin

Comment: Maybe there are some problematic characters in ${timestamp} or ${NC_recDays} that involve such a behavior, but it is difficult to answer without the expanded value of $output. Could you add an `echo $output` in your script and post the result please ?

Answer (score 0):

You get `NameError: name 'string' is not defined` because, well, `string` is not defined. There's no Python builtin called `string`. `os.environ["whatever"]` already has type `str`, so you don't need any conversion.

Of course that's not the only problem. You assigned the env var to `bash_output` but later try to use the variable name `output_test`. Presumably that's a typo, so you also have to change that.

Everything corrected:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
output_test="ip:192.168.1.150,status:up"
export output_test
python -c "$(cat <<'EOF'
import socket
import os
import json
print(os.environ)
bash_output = os.environ['output_test']
sd = dict(u.split(":") for u in bash_output.split(","))
print json.dumps(sd)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 15000))
s.send(bytes(json.dumps(s)))
result = json.loads(s.recv(1024))
print result
s.close()
EOF
)"
```

Then I don't really know what your socket does (unless you provide more info), so you have to make sure that part is correct.

Comment: Now I see that @achampion's fix is essentially the same, though they didn't point out what the error message means.

Comment: FYI there _is_ a [string](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html) module, but it does something else entirely :)

Comment: @Joost Note that I said there's no Python [**builtin**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) called `string`.

Comment: Thank you everyone. Really appreciated and I've gained some extra understanding of Python from you all too!

Comment: @user1556814 you're alternative feeding as an argument works fine.

Comment: @4ae1e1 I got some weird error that looked like a load of machine code. Can't work out what's wrong, as your code looks so similar to mine

Comment: @jewfro Sorry, what error? Edit whatever error into your question. Also, you're better off testing the python program on its own. There's not much going on with Bash.

Comment: @4ae1e1 I got an error when I ran it, I'm not sure what it was, but it was a strange error, 100s of lines, searching all my paths and environment variables. I couldn't see anything wrong and I copied and pasted several times to see if I was adding something. I will try running your code just in python to see.

Comment: @jewfro I didn't edit (or even read) your socket part of the program. Now that I read it, obviously `s.send(bytes(json.dumps(s)))` should be replaced by `s.send(bytes(json.dumps(sd)))`. That might or might not be the problem, without seeing your dump.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. I corrected that just now already for my final version above, sorry! I guess because of my other errors in there, the effect of that particular one had been masked. My error not yours!

Comment: @jewfro Yes, your original python script failed in the fourth line. Python is an interpreted language, so it basically aborts after the first error (techinally, exception), unless you catch it with `try: ... except: ...`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code I have which is working, using @user1556814 solution:

```
output_test="ip:192.168.1.150,status:up"


python -c "$(cat << 'EOF'
import socket
import os
import json
import sys 
bash_output = sys.argv[1]
sd = dict(u.split(":") for u in bash_output.split(","))
print json.dumps(sd)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 15000))
s.send(bytes(json.dumps(sd)))
s.close()
EOF
)" $output_test
```

My question, forgive me, is it safe? It's going to be sending packets of data, perhaps up to 30, between programmes on a local machine. They will almost identical as the above, so very small, simple json objects, likely every 10 seconds. Just the one bash script running each time and outputting the above from the command it has run (with some awk in there too).
As I don't know the language very well, I hope I haven't missed any gotchas? This code really simplifies what I want to do, and if it works, well, I can deepen my python knowledge later, when I have more time and less panic :)

Comment: If that's your use case, then yes, you should use `argv` instead of env var. And I would put the python code into a separate python script rather than putting it in a Bash script within an evil `cat heredoc` construct. And what do you mean by "safe"? For safety you should really quote `$output_test` (i.e., `"$output_test"`). And you might need better parsing than `dict(u.split(":") for u in bash_output.split(","))`, depending on the format of your strings. Other than that, it's safe as long as you can make sure there's no unwanted malicious access.

Comment: @4ae1e1 Yes I don't mean safe in the secure sense, but rather in the unwanted side effects sense. Or In the sense of not personally knowing much of what is going under the hood. Thanks for you tips. I will post up those other errors later when I have sec